# Why is my code to change a UIViewController's View to a UIScrollView not working

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

my code inside of the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method is

```
self.view = UIScrollView
```

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you can't assign classes to Objective-C properties of type UIView; you have to instantiate the class before assigning the object to the property. Try this:

```
self.view = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 480.0)];
```

Comment: Note that this code sets you up for a memory leak.  If sticking to a single line, you'll need to add an autorelease outside of the alloc / init.